# Как получить onFocusChanged ивент в LazyRow для каждого элемента в списке?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility

Я работаю над реализацией accessibility (для людей с ограниченными возможностями, включая незрячих), когда пользователь свайпает влево или вправо, чтобы переместить фокус между элементами списка LazyRow, мне нужно знать индекс элемента в списке, который в данный момент находится в фокусе accessibility.

У меня есть реализация:

```
    LazyRow(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier,
        flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = listState)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(items = episodes, key = { index, _ ->
            "$CARD_KEY$index"
        }) { index, item ->
            item.apply {

            CustomCard(
                episode = item.episode,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .background(
                        BrandedTheme._ui_core__bottomsheet__backgroundColor
                    )
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        if (it.isFocused) {
                            if (listState.isScrollInProgress.not() && selectedEpisodeIndex != -1) {
                                GlobalScope.launch {
                                    listState.scrollToItem(index = index)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {
                        isTraversalGroup = true
                        traversalIndex = -1f
                    },
                index = index
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом, каждый элемент в списке имеет модификатор с свойством - onFocusChanged. Проблема в том, что это событие срабатывает только при инициализации списка, а затем, когда пользователь перемещает фокус доступности (свайпает влево/вправо), то я вижу на экране девайса, что следующий элемент в списке получает фокус, но в коде событие onFocusChanged не срабатывает.

Что я упускаю здесь?

**UPD**

Добавил `onFocusEvent()` и `focusTarget()`, теперь вроде как получаю ивент смены элементов, но 2 проблемы:

1. Все элементы имеею стейт `Inactive` (ни одного active)
2. Индекс не отображает индекс того элемента который сейчас на экране

```
    LazyRow(
        state = listState,
        modifier = modifier,
        flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(lazyListState = listState)
    ) {
        itemsIndexed(items = episodes, key = { index, _ ->
            "$CARD_KEY$index"
        }) { index, item ->
            item.apply {

            CustomCard(
                episode = item.episode,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .wrapContentWidth()
                    .onFocusEvent {
                        Log.e("HERE", "111 onFocusEvent: $index :: $it")
                    }        
                    .background(
                        BrandedTheme._ui_core__bottomsheet__backgroundColor
                    )
                    .onFocusChanged {
                        if (it.isFocused) {
                            if (listState.isScrollInProgress.not() && selectedEpisodeIndex != -1) {
                                GlobalScope.launch {
                                    listState.scrollToItem(index = index)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .focusTarget()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .semantics(mergeDescendants = true) {
                        isTraversalGroup = true
                        traversalIndex = -1f
                    },
                index = index
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Была еще другая идея - я пробовал сделать кастомную `rememberSnapFlingBehavior` так как обратил внимание, что в accessibility mode фокус на экране переключается и он подтягивает следующий элемент, но он не устанавливается по центру экрана (хотя это работает без accessibility mode). Но в итоге эта идея тоже не заработала.